# Trigger: Updating Hyperlink Field on Attachment Parent Record

Tags: trigger, map

I am currently working on an Inforce based integration between Salesforce and InforLN.

As part of this there are custom invoice objects: InForceEW__invoice__c

I am looking to attach PDF copies of invoices to each of these records (they're only about 20kb each so storage is no problem).

I have a flag on the invoice record (Attachment__c) to confirm that a PDF has been attached.  This allows me to filter out records that already have attachments and avoid re-uploading an invoice.

I originally coded a trigger that worked by updating the Attachment__c when an attachment was added to an invoice record:

```
trigger PDFattach on Attachment (before insert) {
    //1 Create a set for IDs of parent objects related to attachments
    Set<ID> AttachIds = new Set<ID>();

    //2 Iterate through the attachments
    for (Attachment a : trigger.new){
        AttachIds.add(a.parentID);
    }

    //3 Use a SOQL query to extract relevant invoice records
    List<InForceEW__invoice__c> invos = [select id, Attachment__c from InForceEW__invoice__c where id in : AttachIds];

    //4 Iterate through the invoice records
    for (InForceEW__invoice__c i: invos){
        //4a update the Attachment field to True
        i.Attachment__c = true;
    }    
    //5 Update the list of invoice records
    update invos;
}
```

Unfortunately though this works well, navigating the invoice and then to attachments is a bit cumbersome on the Salesforce1 app.

I therefore added a field "PDF__c" on the invoice object which is a formula field for a hyperlink to the attached invoice.

An example of a hardcoded formula is:

```
HYPERLINK("https://c.ap1.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P90000008lazb","Invoice PDF")
```

The problem is that I'm having trouble working out how to store the ID of the attachment and replace the formula field with a hyperlink based upon the attachment ID.

Am I best looking at storing the ID in a field on the invoice object and referencing that field value in the hyperlink formula... is that possible? I've created a field for this: AttachID__c

I've tried to learn the use of maps to store the attachment ID and the parentID but I'm struggling. I'm having a lot of difficulty working out how to update the value of the AttachID field in the list of Invoice records from the attachment map.

This is where I got up to:

```
trigger PDFInvoice on Attachment (before insert) {
        //1 Create a Map for IDs of parent objects related to attachments and the value of the link to the attachment
    Map<String,ID> AttachIds = new Map<String, ID>();

    //2 Iterate through the attachments
    for (Attachment a : trigger.new){
        AttachIds.put(a.ID,a.parentID);
    }

    //3 Use a SOQL query to extract relevant invoice records
    List<InForceEW__invoice__c> invos = [select id, Attachment__c, AttachID__c from InForceEW__invoice__c where id in : AttachIds.ID];

    //4 Iterate through the invoice records
    for (InForceEW__invoice__c i: invos){
        //4a update the Attachment field to True
        i.Attachment__c = true;
        i.AttachID__c =  //DON'T KNOW HOW TO UPDATE THIS WITH THE RELEVANT MAP VALUE!
    }    
    //5 Update the list of invoice records
    update invos;

}
```

If anyone can provide any advice I'd greatly appreciate it - I'm determined to learn Apex and was really pleased to get the original trigger working, but right now I'm really struggling!

Comment: Can you tell me Which is parent and which is child Object...If I am correct you are trying to update "AttachID__c" with id ??

Comment: Hi user40138, I managed to solve the problem in the end (below). Thanks for looking into it though. Hope the solution clarifies what I was trying to achieve. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had a couple of epiphanies over the last hour and have managed to get the code working!

I ended up creating the AttachID__c field on the invoice object (which is the parent of the attachment for invoice attachments).  This field holds the ID of the attachment.

I then created a PDF__c formula field with a hyperlink to the attachment:

```
HYPERLINK("https://c.cs5.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file="& AttachID__c ,"Invoice PDF")
```

In my trigger I was able to flag the parent object as having an object by setting a checkbox to true (Attachment__c), however I was having trouble passing the ID of the attachment to the parent invoice record.

I managed to get the maps to work and the attachment flag was been checked, but the attachment ID wasn't being populated.  I eventually realised that was because I needed to switch to "After Insert".

So the final code for the trigger is:

```
trigger PDFInvoice on Attachment (after insert, after update) {
        //1 Create a Map for IDs of parent objects related to attachments and the value of the link to the attachment
    Set<ID> AttachIds = new Set<ID>();

    //2 Iterate through the attachments
    for (Attachment a : trigger.new){
        AttachIds.add(a.parentID);
    }

    //3 Use a SOQL query to extract relevant invoice records and Map the Invoice
    Map <Id, InForceEW__invoice__c> matchingInvoicesMap = new Map <Id, InForceEW__invoice__c> ();

    for (InForceEW__invoice__c invoice : [Select Id, Name From InForceEW__invoice__c Where Id IN :AttachIds])
    {
        matchingInvoicesMap.put(invoice.Id, invoice);
    }
    List <InForceEW__invoice__c> InvoicesToUpdate = new List <InForceEW__invoice__c> ();

    // go through the records in the trigger again and check whether we have found a matching invoice
    for(Attachment a: trigger.New)
    {
        if (matchingInvoicesMap.get(a.ParentId) != null)
        {
            // we found a matching one
            matchingInvoicesMap.get(a.ParentId) .AttachID__c = a.Id;
            matchingInvoicesMap.get(a.ParentId). Attachment__c = true;
            // add it to a separate list and update it
            InvoicesToUpdate.add(matchingInvoicesMap.get(a.ParentId));

        }
    }     
update InvoicesToUpdate;
}
```

Thanks for the support, it's great to have somewhere to come to :)